# React context Api, use Consumer outside provider

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am having a basic doubt about context api. Can we use Context.consumer component outside the context.provider?

I have a component with two select tags having same options. I wrapped the first select with context provider and getting the data as such,

```
<DataProvider loadRestarantsOnWillMount {...this.context}>
            <select  className="select_Restaurent float-right "
                        defaultValue=""
                      >
                        <option>All Restaurants</option>
                        <DataContext.Consumer>
                          {({ restarants }) => {
                            return (
                              restarants &&
                              restarants.map((r, idx) => (
                                <option value={r.id} key={String(idx)}>
                                  {r.name}
                                </option>
                              ))
                            );
                          }}
                        </DataContext.Consumer>
                      </select>
                    </DataProvider>
```

Now, the second select tag is inside a bootstrap modal, and to get the restarants list, I tried to wrap this select with context.consumer,

```
 <DataContext.Consumer>
   {({ restarants }) =>
       restarants &&
        restarants.map((r, idx) => (
           <option value={r.id} key={String(idx)}>
              {r.name}
            </option>
         ))
    }
 </DataContext.Consumer>
```

but do not get the restarants here.

the context is defined in seperate file and the restarants are loaded from api onComponentWillmount of DataProvider component,
If I wrap the second consumer with `<DataProvider>` again, I think there will be an unnecessary api call again.

So, can I acccess consumer outside the provider? or should I have to wrap entire page in the `<DataProvider>`?, which I am trying to avoid, just for two small select tags.

By the way, the whole component already has another context set with `static contextType`, so I can't use Datacontext as the component context.

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap the consumer with the provider at some level. That is required.The way the provider works is by giving it a value prop that you want to provide to the consumer, right? So that provider and its prop need to be some ancestor of your consumer.

Comment: Thank you, needed to clarify that. Also, I wonder if there is a better(elegant) way of doing this, than to wrap entire code with providers, when multiple components requiring same data are spread over a large component.

Comment: @jaysurya Please not that you can use Consumer outside of Provider. It will not alert you that this is the case but won't give you current values from context just the initial ones all the time.